# How to compose a Clojure Query with embedded double quotes

Tags: mysql, string, jdbc, clojure

I want to compose a Clojure query, so that the `lnam` and `fnam` parameters in the where clause are double-quoted. I need them double-quoted, because embedded names contain single quote characters, like "O'BRIEN".

I have been looking at examples for both Clojure queries and embedding double quotes in strings, but am not finding examples of what I want.

This works fine in `lein repl`

```
gic-cmp.core=> (def lnam "O'BRIEN")
#'gic-cmp.core/lnam
gic-cmp.core=> (str """"lnam"""")
"O'BRIEN"
```

But this won't produce a quoted string in the query below.

```
(defn match-this-rec-with-last
    ""
    [gic-id lnam fnam search-date]
    (let [query (str (str "select g.* from gic_employees g where g.processed_date = '" search-date "' ")
                          (str "and g.gic_id = '" gic-id "' and g.last_name = ")
                          """"lnam""""
                          (str " and g.first_name = ")
                          (str """"fnam"""")
                          (str " order by g.processed_date desc "))]
      (println query)
      (j/query db
            [query])))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REPL displays the return value of the str function with quotes around it.

```
(str """"lnam"""")
```

this returns 2 empty strings, lnam, and 2 more empty strings all with quotes around it.

The underlying string is a java.lang.String and the standard java way to include double quotes within a string is to escape it with a backslash.

```
user=> (str "test with \"quoted\" value")
"test with \"quoted\" value"
user=> (println (str "test with \"quoted\" value"))
test with "quoted" value
```

Answer (score 4):

Use ? for query params, jdbc will escape them properly:

```
(defn match-this-rec-with-last
  ""
  [gic-id lnam fnam search-date]
  (let [query [(clojure.string/join " " ["select g.* from gic_employees g where g.processed_date = ?"
                                          "AND g.gic_id = ? and g.last_name = ?"
                                          "AND g.first_name = ?"
                                          "ORDER BY g.processed_date desc"])
               ;; values
               search-date gic-id lnam fnam]]
    (println query)
    (j/query db
             query)))
```

Comment: Many thanks. I was actually looking for ? examples; had seen them a few months ago; and couldn't find them again.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus see Examples at jdbc page https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc#example-usage and https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/06_databases/6-03_manipulating-an-SQL-database.asciidoc